# php artisan optimize NULL.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am setting up an existing Laravel project for the first time in my life,

I am using

- macOS Catlina version 10.15.2
- Mongodb 3.2
- Php 7.2

When I am using composer install I am getting the below error:

> php artisan optimize NULL.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to
>   undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler()

I have gone through multiple links on Stack overflow but no luck , I have deleted vendor folder , and composer.lock multiple times and tried to run composer install but the error is same

Can some body help me to solve this issue

Below is my `composer.json`

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^1.0",
    "moloquent/moloquent": "dev-master",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": "~1.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.9.2",
    "dingo/api": "1.0.x@dev",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0@dev",
    "irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard": "^1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1",
    "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^3.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "milon/barcode": "^5.3",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.3.3",
    "brozot/laravel-fcm": "^1.2",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^6.0",
    "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~2.4",
    "caffeinated/menus": "v3.0.4",
    "laravel-notification-channels/webpush": "^3.0.1",
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.5",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "laravel/passport": "^1.0",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
    "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't get any help , so I started scanning each line of code and found that there is some issue with line  `laravel/framework": "5.3.*"` , I changed it to 5.* and ran composer install, it worked like a charm and yes it installed Laravel 5.3.8 version